# another combinatorial question: permutation, binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics

The problem:
Find the *abc* sequences such as:
*a* is an int between 1-9, *b* and *c* are int between 0-9 and $$a>b>c \,\,;$$
the book posts: $$\binom{9}{3}+\binom{9}{2} = 120.$$
If the digits are taken: *a* from 1-4, *b* and *c* from 0-4 this formula does not work,
$$\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{2} = 20,$$
but if we verify it, the sequences are:
$$210, 310, 320, 321, 410, 420, 421, 430, 431, 432.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to find the number of sequences $abc$ such that $1\leq a\leq n$ and $0\leq b,c\leq n$ with $a>b>c$ - then it is the same as choosing any three distinct elements from $[0,n]$, and then there is only one way to select which one is $a$, which is $b$ and which is $c$. So the answer should be $\binom{n+1}{3}$, since if $0$ is chosen, then the other two are greater than zero and hence $a$ won't be $0$.
As you can see, this is true in your case: you have exactly $\binom{5}{3}=10$ sequences for $n=4$.
For the original question, the answer is $\binom{10}{3}=120$.
The way it was solved in the book is dividing into two cases: none of them is $0$ - $\binom{9}{3}$ options, and if $c=0$ then $\binom{9}{2}$ options. Hence in you case you should have wrote $\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{2}=4+6=10$

Comment: thank you for the good eplanation, the second formula is wrong I was supposed to write $$\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{2} = 10$$,
as you said.

Comment: @blob: If you like an answer you got on this site you should upvote it and accept one that answers you question in the best possible way. Don't see this comment as a request to upvote/accept *my* answer, but rather as general policy on this site - and I wrote it because I see that you didn't accept any answers yet. Accepting an answer makes other people know that you got the desired answer and there is no need to seek for different solutions for you. More on accepting answers can be found here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Comment: how to solve if a>=b>=c?

Comment: The same way, but divide into three cases: (1) all are distinct (2) exactly two are equal (3) all are equal

Comment: all are equal: $$\binom{3}{1}$$;
two are equal: there are 2 cases, a,b are equal or b,c are equal but i don't know the formula,
all are distinct: the same.

Comment: In case (1) you have $\binom{n}{3}$, in case (2) - $2\binom{n-1}{2}+\binom{n}{1}$ and in case (3) - $\binom{n-1}{1}$